# Is it possible to make a folder in an SVN repository to point to a folder in another repository?

Tags: svn, repository, directory, svn-repository

I'm currently working on a very small open source project for Maemo 5. (Namely [Sticky Notes](http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=57049).)
I would like to incorporate some stuff from the [Hildon Extras](http://wiki.maemo.org/Hildon-Extras) project.

It seems that they have no binary packages, just an SVN repository, and the developers who use it just copy-paste the sources from Hildon-Extras to their own repository.

While I don't have any problem with that, the only issue with this method is versioning. If I just copy-paste their source files, there is no way I could know when they update them. (Unless I regularly check it manually, of course.)

So, the question is this: is there a way for me to make a folder in my SVN repository point to the source folder in their repository, so that it would automatically update their stuff for me?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**

Mwilson's recommendation to use svn externals just did the trick! **Thank you!**
The [TortoiseSVN page about externals](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html) also helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an [externals definition](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html).

Comment: This is *exactly* what you need.